# my ConversionService encountered 500 error code

Tags: spring-mvc

I am learning the spring mvc and when i try to use the ConversionService ,i encounterrd 500

```
@RequestMapping("/handle81")
public String handle81(@RequestParam("user")User user,ModelMap modelMap) {
    System.out.println(user);
    modelMap.put("user", user);
    return "/user/success";
}
```

this is the handler method ,i've put the @RequestMapping("/user") at the class
and the converter

```
public class StringToUserConverter implements Converter<String, User> {
public User convert(String source) {
    System.out.println(source);
    User user=new User();
        String[] item=source.split(":");
        user.setUserName(item[0]);
        user.setPassword(item[1]);
        user.setName(item[2]);
    return user; 
}
```

}

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" />
<bean id="conversionService"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <list>
            <bean class="com.baobaotao.domain.StringToUserConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

so when i browse

```
http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc/user/handle81.html?user=asdf:asdf:fdas
```

it gets 500 and prints nothing at the console(i use maven-jetty to do the test)
thx for helping~

Comment: 500 is 'Server Error', find out where the exception is being logged & what it is.

Comment: And good luck on your site security.. you'll be exposing every user's name & password to the entire Internet, plus allowing anybody to easily spoof their way in :)

Comment: nono,i am just learning..and this is just coded for practice...

Comment: but i don't know why there prints nothing besides the exception stack...no matter i used maven-jetty for test or i deployed it to tomcat

Answer (score 0):

I think your Request URL may not be not matching. You specify "/handle81" in the annotation, but are requesting "/handle81.html".

It's hard to tell, without further information, whether the problem is matching & dispatching the request to the handler;  or in the conversion.

Try another handler with the parameter of type String, and see whether you can call that successfully. At least you'll then know where the problem is.

---

**And what is the exception stack-trace? Why didn't you post it?** That's your most important clue & you should always post the ex message & top few lines/ where it was thrown, when you ask a question. It should be in either the application or Tomcat/ other server logs.